# Является ли в JavaScript переменная объектом?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Является ли в JavaScript переменная объектом как в ЯП Ruby??

Comment: Переменная, в которой хранится объект, является объектом. Переменная, в которой хранится примитивный тип, не является объектом.

Comment: А тогда почему в ruby переменные которые содержат примитивный вид считается объектом??

Comment: Потому что это Ruby. А это JS. Разные ЯП, разные парадигмы, разные подходы, разное назначение, разная история становление языка, разные люди создавали язык из разных стран.

Comment: Мне вот тут еще в голову пришло. А что вы подразумеваете под объектом? Может, мы о разных вещах говорим) Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте туда ваше определения объекта.

Comment: Я имею в виду объект как набор свойств. Или в ruby и js понимание объекта разные?

Comment: Я объект понимаю как предмет который имеет свойства, например ручка она имеет свойства : цвет размер вес.  и  понимаю что в ruby  переменая имеет свойства, а в js  переменная имеет свойства ?)

Answer (score 3):

Переменная в JS является указателем. Тоесть она указывает на область пямяти где содержится значение (примитивное или обьект или функция).

В зависимости от значения хранящегостя в этой области памяти перемнная может быть одним из примитивных типов данных или обьектом (функция и массив в джаваскрипте тоже являются обьектами).

Кроме того есть такое понятие как обьекты обертки. Например у вас есть есть переменнаая содержащая простой тип данных стринг. Это не обьект. Но вы можете к ней обратится и вызвать методы обьекта `String`.

```js
let str1 = 'hello world';

console.log(str1.toUpperCase())
```

Так происходит потому что интерпритатор за кадром делает приблизительно следующее

```js
let str1 = 'hello world';

console.log((new String(str1)).toUpperCase())
```

Тоесть оборачивает примитивный тип в соответствующий его типу обьект.

Comment: Еще бы описать, когда переменная передается по значению, а когда по ссылке. И будет совсем хорошо!

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko имхо это офтопик. да и расписать концепцию передачи по ссылке и по значению плюс кейсы применения это та еще простыня.

Comment: Ну так это практически главное отличие между примитивным типом и объектом!